# How do I replicate a C++ cast of Windows SOCKADDR_BTH to a SOCKADDR in Rust?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, bluetooth, rust

I am writing a Bluetooth utility on Windows in Rust, using winsock2 (but happy to use any other libraries) and have hit a roadblock. The following C++ sample from the [Windows Bluetooth Connection Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Connection-e3263296/sourcecode?fileId=42913&pathId=2083610005) is what I am using as a reference:.

```
SOCKADDR_BTH SockAddrBthServer;
# code to set SockAddrBthServer vals in here 
connect(LocalSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &SockAddrBthServer, sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH));
```

The structs are defined like so:

```
typedef struct _SOCKADDR_BTH
{
    USHORT      addressFamily;  // Always AF_BTH
    BTH_ADDR    btAddr;         // Bluetooth device address
    GUID        serviceClassId; // [OPTIONAL] system will query SDP for port
    ULONG       port;           // RFCOMM channel or L2CAP PSM
} SOCKADDR_BTH, *PSOCKADDR_BTH;


typedef struct sockaddr {

#if (_WIN32_WINNT < 0x0600)
    u_short sa_family;
#else
    ADDRESS_FAMILY sa_family;           // Address family.
#endif //(_WIN32_WINNT < 0x0600)

    CHAR sa_data[14];                   // Up to 14 bytes of direct address.
} SOCKADDR, *PSOCKADDR, FAR *LPSOCKADDR;
```

How do I replicate the `(struct sockaddr *) &SockAddrBthServer` cast from the connect line above in Rust? So far, I'm making use of the winapi, user32 and ws2_32 crates.

Here is the Rust version of the [`connect` function from the ws2_32 crate](https://retep998.github.io/doc/ws2_32/fn.connect.html).

```
pub unsafe extern "system" fn connect(s: SOCKET, name: *const SOCKADDR, namelen: c_int) -> c_int
```

Comment: 1) Can you show us what you have tried so far? I don't see any Rust code in there. 2) Requesting such examples is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: What you say _"How do I replicate `(struct sockaddr *) &SockAddrBthServer` in rust?"_ do you mean how to create a similar structure, or how to create something with identical representation in memory?

Comment: @E_net4, I tried using transmute like so: 
`mem::transmute::<SOCKADDR_BTH, ws2def::SOCKADDR>(bt_sock_addr)` but transmute does not allow different size structs.

@PeterHall, the rust version of the connection function (as defined in ws2_32) accepts a `*const SOCKADDR` which I assume works like the C++ version. Which I take to mean it needs the data from the `SOCKADDR_BTH` but typecast as `SOCKADDR`.

Comment: Don't try to truncate. Instead write an explicit conversion function from the larger struct to the smaller one.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand the issue now. I think the connect function is not really respecting the type and instead using a combination of the `family` short and the third parameter to decide how to interpret the pointer. I'm guessing I'll have to write my own FFI code to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overthinking the problem. If Windows says it's cool to cast a `SOCKADDR_BTH` pointer to a `SOCKADDR` pointer, then just do that. In Rust, you have to add one extra cast to leave the safe world of references and get to a raw pointer, then you can cast that to whatever you want:

```
use std::mem;

struct SomeErrorType;

fn example(LocalSocket: SOCKET) -> Result<SOCKADDR_BTH, SomeErrorType> {
    unsafe {
        let SockAddrBthServer: SOCKADDR_BTH = mem::uninitialized();
        let retval = connect(
            LocalSocket,
            &SockAddrBthServer as *const SOCKADDR_BTH as *const SOCKADDR,
            mem::size_of::<SOCKADDR_BTH>() as i32,
        );
        // PERFORM REAL ERROR CHECKING HERE
        if retval == 42 {
            Ok(SockAddrBthServer)
        } else {
            Err(SomeErrorType)
        }
    }
}
```

(Untested because I don't have a Windows machine handy)

Under the hood, this will only work as long as the initial members of `SOCKADDR_BTH` exactly match the members of `SOCKADDR`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. My understanding of Rust pointers was all wrong. Also, for the sake of others who come across this - I had to add the `repr(packed)` attribute to my SOCKADDR_BTH struct otherwise it was 40 bytes instead of the expected 30.

Comment: @TomGangemi I'd encourage you to find the `SOCKADDR_BTH ` struct in the appropriate Windows crate or to submit a PR to one to add it. Maintaining your own representation of it is fraught with peril.

Comment: @Sheepmaster, I figured that would be the proper way to do things but was just focused on getting the code working for now.